# How can I create function pointers from a string input in MATLAB?

Tags: string, matlab, function-pointers, function-handle

If I use the `inline` function in MATLAB I can create a single function name that could respond differently depending on previous choices:

```
if (someCondition)
  p = inline('a - b','a','b');
else
  p = inline('a + b','a','b');
end

c = p(1,2);
d = p(3,4);
```

But the inline functions I'm creating are becoming quite epic, so I'd like to change them to other types of functions (i.e. m-files, subfunctions, or nested functions).

Let's say I have m-files like `Mercator.m`, `KavrayskiyVII.m`, etc. (all taking a value for `phi` and `lambda`), and I'd like to assign the chosen function to `p` in the same way as I have above so that I can call it many times (with variable sized matrices and things that make using `eval` either impossible or a total mess).

I have a variable, `type`, that will be one of the names of the functions required (e.g. `'Mercator'`, `'KavrayskiyVII'`, etc.). I figure I need to make `p` into a pointer to the function named inside the `type` variable. Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Option #1:

Use the [`str2func`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2func.html) function (assumes the string in `type` is the same as the name of the function):

```
p = str2func(type);  % Create function handle using function name
c = p(phi, lambda);  % Invoke function handle
```

**NOTE:** The documentation mentions these limitations:

> Function handles created using `str2func` do not have access to variables outside of their local workspace or to nested functions. If your function handle contains these variables or functions, MATLAB® throws an error when you invoke the handle.

### Option #2:

Use a [SWITCH](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html) statement and [function handles](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html):

```
switch type
  case 'Mercator'
    p = @Mercator;
  case 'KavrayskiyVII'
    p = @KavrayskiyVII;
  ...                    % Add other cases as needed
end
c = p(phi, lambda);      % Invoke function handle
```

### Option #3:

Use [EVAL](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) and [function handles](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html) (suggested by [Andrew Janke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820802/how-can-i-create-function-pointers-from-a-string-input-in-matlab/1820818#comment1711379_1820818)):

```
p = eval(['@' type]);  % Concatenate string name with '@' and evaluate
c = p(phi, lambda);    % Invoke function handle
```

As Andrew points out, this avoids the limitations of `str2func` and the extra maintenance associated with a switch statement.

Comment: How about Option 3: dynamic function handle constructors: "p = eval(['@' type])". Avoids the str2func limitation without a hand-maintained switch statement.